# How to fix camera_calibration giving error on save in Noetic

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running camera_calibration in Noetic:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.026 image:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/raspicam_node
```

It works fine finding the calibration parameters, but when I try to save the parameters, I get an error from Python 2.x code.  Is anyone else getting this problem?  Seems bad that we have Python 2.x code in there.  Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):81604   Duration: 69.231470 / 84.882752               0
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py", line 273, in on_mouse
self.c.do_save()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 577, in do_save
self.do_tarfile_save(tf) # Must be overridden in subclasses
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 889, in do_tarfile_save
taradd(name, cv2.imencode(".png", im)[1].tostring())
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 877, in taradd
if isinstance(buf, basestring): 
NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined
```

The command `basestring` is Python 2 command that is now `str` in Python 3.  So I think that's the problem.  I can't directly edit this file though, so don't know how to fix the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367500/how-to-fix-camera_calibration-giving-error-on-save-in-noetic/) by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-12-11**:
This has actually been fixed in https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/pull/552 in June, but the [latest release is from May](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_default.html?q=camera_cal).
So you should probably install that from sources...

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2020-12-11**:
That's great.  A couple questions

1. Do you mean I need to install all of ROS Noetic from source, or just the ros-perception?
2. If the latter, would I: sudo apt-get remove ros-noetic-perception and build it from source in my catkin_ws?
3. Finally, any idea when the next release that incorporates this will be?
   Thank you!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-12-11**:\

1. No, only the package in question. Maybe the full repo (`image_pipeline`). Obviously, if there are any dependencies that you need that haven't been installed, those as well. But from the change this looks good.
2. No, just put it in your workspace and it takes precedence. See [Workspace Chaining](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) for some background
3. Sorry no. The repo seems not very active. You could check if there is an issue open for a noetic release and voice your support for that to happen, or, if not, open a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @mgruhler pointed out, this is a bug that has been fixed https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/pull/552, but is not yet part of the standard Noetic release.  I raised an issue to sync image_pipeline with Noetic.  But in the mean time, the solution that @mgruhler suggests works great:

Simply clone the latest https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline into your catkin_ws/src folder, build it, and it will take precedence.

---

Originally posted by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) with karma: 35 on 2020-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-12-12**:
The release [has been triggered](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/27751). Once this PR is merged, one still has to wait for the next package sync, but this shouldn't take toooo long then. Depending on whether it makes it in the next sync or the one after that, maybe end of January?

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2020-12-12**:
Excellent!